# Typescript: Ограничить тип второго аргумента функции типом первого аргумента

Tags: typescript

Есть функция, которая первым аргументом принимает callback c параметром, вторым аргументом принимает параметр для этого callback'a.

```
const callback = (p: number) => {
  console.log(p);
};

const call = (cb, param) => {
  cb(param);
};
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вызов со строкой во втором аргументе `call(callback, '8')` был некорректен.

Вариант описанный ниже не годится, коллбэки заранее незвестны.

```
const someFunc = (
  cb: typeof callback,
  param: Parameters<typeof callback>[0],
) => {
  cb(param);
};
```

Comment: Какие ограничения накладываются на параметр?

Comment: более общий вариант: `function call<T extends (...args:any[])=>any>(cb:T, ...param: Parameters<T>) {`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [дженерики](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
const call = <T>(cb: (arg: T) => unknown, param: T) => {
  cb(param);
};
```